# Adding WCF service reference in ASP.NET MVC app fails

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wcf

I'm trying to add a WCF service to my ASP.NET MVC application. After setting it up, I get an error whenever I want to test it.

Here is my code:

**BackgroundTask.svc**

```
public class BackgroundTask : IBackgroundTask
{
    public void ShutdownVm()
    {
    }

    public void UpdateTable()
    {
    }
}
```

**IBackgroundTask.cs**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IBackgroundTask
{
    [OperationContract]
    void ShutdownVm();
    [OperationContract]
    void UpdateTable();
}
```

**Web.config**

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="bgtBehaviour" name="IsolutionsAzureManager.Controllers.BackgroundTask">
        <endpoint address="BackgroundTask" binding="basicHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="" name="" contract="IsolutionsAzureManager.Controllers.IBackgroundTask" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:44304/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="bgtBehaviour">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

So, whenever I want to test my WFC service, I get this error:
Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from `https://localhost:44304/Controllers/BackgroundTask.svc`

Error: The HTML document does not contain Web service discovery information.

Can anyone see the mistake?

Comment: Can you try `webHttpBinding` instead of `binding="basicHttpBinding"`?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are attempting to acquire the mex endpoint over Https, you'll also need to switch to [mexHttpsBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa967391(v=vs.110).aspx) and 
to enable the `httpsGetEnabled` setting:

```
 <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
```

Alternatively, obtain the endpoint via http (`http://localhost:44304/Controllers/BackgroundTask.svc`) and then just switch back to https once the client has built the service reference artifacts.